# Rails site accepts https request, doesn't see http request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, browser, dns

Our site is rejecting HTTP requests, unless you've previously visited via HTTPS.

If you navigate to `https://sitename.com` the server responds fine, site loads, etc. And thereafter navigating to `sitename.com` (not `https`) also redirects automatically to `https://sitename.com`. We've set `force_ssl = true`

But if after clearing my cache/cookies I first go to just `sitename.com`, the request never makes it to the server. (Or at least that's my current thinking since there's no log activity whatsoever.)

Here are the error codes from various browsers:

Chrome: `Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
Firefox: `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at sitename.com`
Opera: `The webpage is not available. Opera's connection attempt to www.ticketscience.com was rejected`
Safari: Somehow successfully redirects to HTTPS, even after resetting all all browser history/cache/cookies

Is this a DNS issue? Something else? I'm not sure where even to start looking.

UPDATE:
In my nginx conf file I was only listening on port 443 (for SSL). I added `listen 80` and now the error message has changed to:

```
400 Bad Request

The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

Answer (score 0):

It was simply a manner of adding:

```
listen 80;
```

and removing

```
ssl on;
```

from my `nginx.conf` file.

It now listens to both http and https requests on the same server:

`server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name sitename.com;
        ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/certs/SSL.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/certs/server.key;
}`